# flutter_offline does not check accurately in iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using [flutter_offline](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_offline) package to check connectivity in an app but it seems to be not working perfectly in iOS since it keeps showing not connected dialog several times even phone is connected.

This simple app for testing.
Can someone point out the issue?

code:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: OfflineBuilder(
          connectivityBuilder: (
            BuildContext context,
            ConnectivityResult connectivity,
            Widget child,
          ) {
            final bool connected = connectivity != ConnectivityResult.none;
            if (connected) {
              return child;
            } else {
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (context) {
                      return const AlertDialog(
                        title: Text('No Internet'),
                        content: Text('You are not connected to the internet'),
                      );
                    });
              });

              /// Print to show that is poping up the dialog several times
              print('No internet');
            }
            return child;
          },
          errorBuilder: (context) => const Center(child: Text("Error")),
          child: const Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Connected to the internet',
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can run this app in simulator or emulator so it's not work properly.
so you can user real device to test internet connectivity in flutter apps.

Comment: I used them all, it works fine in Android Emulator and real device, but it does not work perfectly in simulator or real device.

Comment: Please check this link "https://github.com/jogboms/flutter_offline/issues/6" to better understating in IOS device

Comment: Not closely related.

Comment: so you can use its alternative package or code like connectivity_plus package https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus

Comment: Yes I would use this one